# Some categories are not showing up in the mobile menu of my site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress website which has an advanced search feature. But I don't know why, some categories are not shown in the mobile version.
[Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZUFu.png)

This is the desktop version of the site in which the categories are shown.

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxe5H.png)

This is the mobile version in which the categories don't appear. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to check the @media CSS options on your  tags , looks like there is a scroller on your mobile version, you may find the categories are "hidden", use google chrome or similar developer tools to inspect the site when activating a mobile view.  Best way to debug these type of issues is to learn how to use the developer tools and inspectors in the main stream browsers.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/